# Repay a loan early

Tags: europa-universalis-3

Is it possible to repay a loan earlier and perhaps circumvent the additional interest for the rest of the period? If this is possible how do I do this? Is there a loan screen somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - you have to wait until the due date, and pay the full interest.